# using cytoscape.js plugins from cdn

Tags: javascript, cdn, cytoscape.js

I'm working with an online tool, essentially a wiki that i can't add files to so I have to reference them from a CDN.

I'm using cytoscape.js - and it works fine with all the built in functions - but I want to add a layout like cola - and I can't figure out how to do it.  I tried html:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.16.1/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-cola@2.4.0/cytoscape-cola.min.js"></script>
```

but window.cola doesn't exist.   I tried using javascript modules - ie

```js
import cytoscape from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.16.1/cytoscape.min.js";
import cytoscapeCola from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-cola@2.4.0/cytoscape-cola.min.js";
```

which I've never used before, but obviously I don't know what I'm doing, because I just get various errors about them not exporting a default, and can't read "webcola of undefined".  Obviously there's something I don't understand about modules.  Please help!

Comment: Did you see this demo file of Cola: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cola/blob/master/demo.html ? You also need to add <script src="https://unpkg.com/webcola/WebCola/cola.min.js"></script> to be able to use Cola from CDN.

Comment: thanks - that worked, and oddly would never have occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

Just to answer the question here instead of in the comments, with the complete solution, here is what worked for me:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.23.0/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/webcola/WebCola/cola.min.js"></script>`,
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-cola@2.4.0/cytoscape-cola.min.js"></script>
```

You needed to include not only the `cytoscape-cola` package, but also the `cola` package itself.

You might need to update version numbers, depending on where you are coming from in the future.